# Get elements from list in equal manner, algorithm or math equation

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have a list of elements ex: `[1, 10, 10]` which represents the number of products I have of every type.
The user want's to buy `10` products of every type, equal.
So the result list will be `[1, 5, 4]` or `[1, 4, 5]`.
I did this by a while and for loop, iterating all the elements in list, increase the counter if I didn't achieved the max quantity, until I get 10 products, or all the stock is empty.

But I have some performance trouble in the case of very big data, and I need to apply this in multiple locations.

My question is, if I can do this in a math equation or a better algorithm.
For a math equation I extracted this data to be solved, but I have too many unknown variables:

```
21/x = a
21/y = b
21/z = c
a + b + c = 10
```

Where 21 is the sum of all products, and 10 is the quantity of products that the user needs.

Comment: Isn't `[0,5,5]` a solution?    Add your code, it may be optimized

Comment: No, because I didn't get all type of products, I need to get from all products in an equal mode.

Comment: I don't believe an overall math equation can help since you could potentially have `n` unknowns with only one constraint that the sum equals some value `k`. Perhaps a dynamic programming approach?

Comment: I already broke down my main problem, and I arrived to this which I don't know how to tear apart. @Miket25

Comment: Do you only care about finding only one solution, or finding every solution?

Comment: @Miket25, only one, if that solution takes all type of products, in an equal manner

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "equal manner?"

Comment: @Miket25  I have products `[3, 3, 3]` and the user want's 5 products, I will give him `[2, 2, 1]`, not `[3, 1, 1]` or `[3, 2, 0]`. I try to take as many products from all locations balanced, If I have enough.

Comment: Is there a measurement that you can define as for what is balanced from a mathematical view? It looks to be that the definition of balanced is the count of every item bought is no more than +- 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An O(n) solution (with O(n log(n)) sortings):

```
amounts = [1, 10, 10]
left_to_buy = 12

sorted_amounts = list(sorted([amount, index] for index, amount in enumerate(amounts)))

for idx, (amount, _) in enumerate(sorted_amounts):
    buy = min(left_to_buy//(len(amounts)-idx), amount)
    sorted_amounts[idx][0] -= buy
    left_to_buy -= buy

final_amounts = [a for a, i in sorted(sorted_amounts, key = lambda t: t[1])]
bought = [amount - final_amounts[i] for i, amount in enumerate(amounts)]

print(final_amounts, bought)
#[0, 5, 4] [1, 5, 6]
```

We first sort the list of available items (we keep their indices in a tuple in order to put the list back in original order at the end).

Then, we remove from each item its share of what is left to buy, or all of it if we don't have enough.

In the end, we put back the list in original order

Edit: I had missed the fact that your list is already sorted... In this case, it gets much shorter:

```
amounts = [1, 10, 10]
left_to_buy = 12

res = [] 

for idx, amount in enumerate(amounts): 
    buy = min(left_to_buy//(len(amounts)-idx), amount) 
    left_to_buy -= buy 
    res.append(buy) 

print(res) 
# [1, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Close, but the OP specified that a given solution must have the constraint that every item in the list is included at least once i.e. an item can't be bought zero times.

Comment: It can't be bought 0 times, unless there's 0 stock available.

Comment: If there's an item in stock, the solution you gave still gives the option of not buying it. `l = [1,10,10]` need to buy `10` gave `[0,6,5]` as a solution.

Comment: @Miket25 These are the **final** amounts = what is left, the second list (named **bought**) is what has been bought, and for the case you give, it returns `[1, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Seems a quite good solution, I was with my head in math and didn't realize that, thank you, I will wait a little in case a better answer appears, but thank you. @Miket25 the stock will not be 0, because I already extract , filtered and ordered the results from db.

Comment: @jalanga For lots of such problems, working on sorted data makes things much easier. What makes it a bit ugly here is the need to restore the order of the original list.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille What do you think about this:
 
     ```amounts = [1, 10, 10]

     left_to_buy = 12

     sorted_amounts = list(sorted([amount, index] for index, amount in 
      enumerate(amounts)))

     res = []
     for idx, (amount, _) in enumerate(sorted_amounts):
         if amount == 0:
            continue
         buy = min(left_to_buy//(len(amounts)-idx), amount)
         sorted_amounts[idx][0] -= buy
         left_to_buy -= buy
         res.append(buy)

     print(res)```

Comment: @jalanga It doesn't keep the order. With `amounts = [10, 1, 10]` you will also get `[1, 5, 6]`, which is incorrect. Also, I removed the useless `if amount == 0: ...`

Comment: I will never have amounts `[10, 1, 10]` because I get them sorted from db.

Comment: @jalanga Oh, I had missed that one... So, I edited the answer for this much simpler case!